# Mount a subdirectory from an already mounted drive with fstab

Tags: mount, fstab, ntfs

I have mounted an external NTFS HD at startup and want to bind a subdirectory to my ~/Documents folder. For this, I added the entries below to fstab, based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47222/how-to-mount-multiple-directories-on-the-same-partition):

```
# Local HD Mounts
UUID=XXXXXXXXXX   /mnt/dpvs     auto    nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0       0

# Local binds
/mnt/dpvs/Documents     /home/username/Documents   none    defaults,bind   0       0
```

I can mount the external HD (first entry), but the second entry doesn't work at startup. The directory is empty, Devices shows a "Documents" mount, and unmounting gives me an error (`umount: /home/username/Documents: umount failed: Operation not permitted`). Strangely, if I boot without the binding entry, then add it to fstab and remount with `mount -a`, it works.

What can I do to mount this subdirectory?

Comment: Perhaps you can make use of systemd mount units, to add a `x-systemd.requires=` dependency? See for example [How do I set up bind mounts on startup correctly in the systemd world?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490282/65304)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the mount of that external drive is not yet ready at the time the mount bind is called in fstab. That could be helped by executing the mount command later during startup, e.g. by placing it in the `/etc/rc.local` file, or, probably better because that way is still by default setup in the latest Ubuntu versions, in a cron job.

To create a cronjob, open the crontab file with the command

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Add your mount command as in

```
@reboot mount --bind /mnt/dpvs/Documents /home/username/Documents
```

Save and close the crontab file. The command will be executed after every reboot.

You may eventually delay booting a little more by introducing a wait time (e.g. 1 second) with the `sleep` command:

```
@reboot ( sleep 1 ; mount --bind /mnt/dpvs/Documents /home/username/Documents )
```